# Have `solve_ivp` return partial result when interrupted

Tags: python, scipy, ode, scientific-computing

I use `scipy`'s [`solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) to solve a differential equation. sometimes the integration takes too long and I want to abort it, but return the partial result that was obtained so far.

If I set a time limit in advance I can hack the `events` argument to check if too much time has elapsed and then stop the integration, but this is hacky and also I would prefer having it "interactive", probaby using `KeyboardInterrupt` or something of this sort.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `scipy.integrate.ode` or the underlying solver classes of `solve_ivp` as that allows a direct control of the integration process.

Comment: @LutzL: That looks like it should be an answer.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks. It works. do you want to post that as an answer so that I'll accept it?